# how to Aggregate files or merge

Tags: linux, r, awk

Can any one help to merge defferent files by common data (columns)? please =(

```
file1.txt

ID   Kg   Year   
3454  1000  2010
3454  1200  2011
3323  1150  2009
2332  1000  2011
3454  1156  201

file2.txt

ID    Place
3454  A1
3323  A2
2332  A6
5555  A9

file 1+2

ID     Kg   Year Place
3454  1000  2010 A1
3454  1200  2011 A1
3323  1150  2009 A2
2332  1000  2011 A6
3454  1156  2013 A1
```

So second file should be connected to first. As you can see ID 5555 from file 2 just not using.

How to do it in linux or....

Comment: this has been asked multiple times in this site. Better do some research before asking. Also, note you can [edit] the question to make it look nicer : )

Comment: Also check `?merge` in R

Comment: search for `[linux] join` Good luck.

Comment: using `awk` this should be `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' f2 f1`

Comment: using r: merge(dat1,dat2,by="ID", all.y=FALSE)

Comment: I am puzzled to see why this question gets upvoted. Hovering the upvote I see `This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear`. I don't think it is neither of them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about maintaining the order of lines, use karakfa's `join` command.

To keep the original order of lines, use awk

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {place[$1]=$2; next}
    $1 in place {print $0, place[$1]}
' file2.txt file1.txt | column -t
```

```
ID    Kg    Year  Place
3454  1000  2010  A1
3454  1200  2011  A1
3323  1150  2009  A2
2332  1000  2011  A6
3454  1156  201   A1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you start with sorted files, the tool is `join`.  In your case, you can sort on the fly.

```
join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

The headers will be joined as well but won't appear on top.  Pipe to `sort -r`

Comment: pipe to `sort -n`, and the header will pop back to the top. Then pipe into `column -t` to make the output pretty.